# Entity Framework Multiple Column as Primary Key by Fluent Api

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

***These are my simplified domain classes.***

```cs
public class ProductCategory
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
} 

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentCategoryId { get; set;} 
}
```

***This is my mapping class. But it doesn't work.***

```cs
public class ProductCategoryMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ProductCategory>
{
    public ProductCategoryMap()
    {
        ToTable("ProductCategory");
        HasKey(pc => pc.ProductId);
        HasKey(pc => pc.CategoryId);
    }
}
```

***How should I map these classes to provide, so that one product can be seen in multiple categories?***

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Use anonymous type object instead of 2 separated statements:

```cs
HasKey(pc => new { pc.ProductId, pc.CategoryId });
```

From Microsoft Docs: [EntityTypeConfiguration.HasKey Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.entitytypeconfiguration-1.haskey)

> If the primary key is made up of multiple properties then specify an anonymous type including the properties. For example, in C# `t => new { t.Id1, t.Id2 }` and in Visual Basic .Net `Function(t) New With { t.Id1, t.Id2 }`.

Comment: For me, in VB.NET, it was `Function(t) With { t.Id1, t.id2 }` that did the trick (rather than "From").

Comment: Is it possible to convert non-primitive value object containing two fields? : `public class MyId { public int CompanyId; public int UserId } `

Comment: Thanks to you, I learned this usage. Before I searched a lot time but I got nothing about this. By the way, is it called AlternateKey as well?