# EF6, Composite Key, is annotation enough? Or Do I have to also use Fluent API?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 3 entities:

```
public class AspNetUser
{
  public string Id {get; set;}
}

public class Event
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
}

public class UserEvent
{
    [Column(Order=0), Key, ForeignKey("AspNetUsers")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [Column(Order=1), Key, ForeignKey("Events")]
    public int EventId { get; set; }

    public DateTime EnrolTime { get; set; }

    public virtual AspNetUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see that, the UserEvent is just a relationship table which has both UserId and EventId from 2 tables.

My question is:

1. Is annotation enough to tell EF to create the 2 foreign keys? Or I have to also use Fluent API to do it in the **OnModelCreating() method** in the DbContext class? Or I have to create a configuration class to do so?
   I saw something in this post(it makes me confused):

[Entity Framework Multiple Column as Primary Key by Fluent Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454696/entity-framework-multiple-column-as-primary-key-by-fluent-api)

2. ForeignKey("X")
   I guess the X should be the table name rather than the entity's name, right?
   E.g. X should be the AspNetUsers(which is in the database), rather than AspNetUser which is the entity name.

Thank you.

Comment: Annotations are enough. Are you creating a one-to-one relationship or a one-to-many? Are you you using EF 6?

Comment: hi @JasonlPrice I'm using EF 6. User to Event: Many to Many. So that's the reason why I need to create UserEvent entity.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's enough using Data Annotations, but the problem  is you need to specify in the [`ForeignKey`](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) attribute the name of navigation property`that represents the relationship it is a foreign key for:

```
public class UserEvent
{
    [ Key,Column(Order=0), ForeignKey("User")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [ Key,Column(Order=1), ForeignKey("Event")]
    public int EventId { get; set; }

    public DateTime EnrolTime { get; set; }

    public virtual AspNetUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, you can apply the `ForeignKey` annotation to the navigation property and tell it which property is the foreign key for the relationship:

```
public class UserEvent
{
    [Key,Column(Order=0)]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [Key,Column(Order=1)]
    public int EventId { get; set; }

    public DateTime EnrolTime { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual AspNetUser User { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EventId")]
    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Ha, I got it. so the X should be the Navigation Property. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class UserEvent
{
    public DateTime EnrolTime { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual AspNetUser User { get; set; }

    public int EventId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EventId")]
    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
}
```